# Why isn't the unit square in $\Bbb{R}^2$ a 1-dimentional $C^0$ differential structure

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Consider $C$ the unit square in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Then $C$ is in bijection with the unit interval $(0,1)$.

Then isn't $C$ by definition a 1-dimentional $C^0$ differential structure? It seems to fulfill all the requirements because the bijection in question are not required to be homeomorphisms, just bijections.

Comment: I would say, a $C^0$ coordinate chart has to be a homeomorphism. Or at least the coordinate change maps should.

Comment: The definition of topological manifold does, but for some reason not the one of differential structure

Comment: Is your $C$ the full square $[0,1]^2$ or its boundary? In both cases there may be a bijection with $\>]0,1[\>$, but such a "set theoretic" bijection has nothing to do with the topological or manifold structure on the domain and range.

Comment: Its just the "open square" without the boundary. That's my problem with the definition. When I looked up the definition of topological manifold, the charts involved were required to be homeomorphisms. Here in the case of differential structures they're required just to be bijections

Comment: I am quite sure your issue is with the definition. Definitions are not always careful with extreme cases like 0-dimension. It could have been that the homeomorphism was IMPLIED in whatever definition you're using. What is zero times differentiability after all?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking of $C$ as just a set, you can of course use a bijection $C \to (0,1)$ to transfer both the topological and smooth structure of the interval to $C,$ making it a smooth manifold; but this topology of course has nothing to do with the usual one we put on $C$.

If you're considering $C$ as already being a topological space (with the subspace topology $\mathbb R^2$), then your definition of a chart/differentiable structure should include the requirement that the chart maps are homeomorphisms; so in this case your approach will fail, since $C$ and $(0,1)$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I understand that if we consider $C$ as already being a topological space, then the bijections we define have to be homeomorphisms in order to preserve the topology. About your first paragraph: does that imply that we can see $C$ as a 1-dimensional smooth manifold (with the messy topology induced by the bijection with the unit interval), and as a 2-dimensional manifold with the usual topology? Because for some reason I thought the dimension was an "invariant" of the set, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @matboy: yes - if you're allowed to change the topology, any set with cardinality of the reals can be made a manifold of any dimension - this is just a consequence of the well-known fact that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ have the same cardinality. The dimension is only an invariant once you fix a topology.

Comment: Ok makes sense, thank you